# Unable to sign a partially signed transaction with solana-py

Tags: python, solana, anchor-solana

in order to buy something on MagicEden, I'm using an endpoint called buy_now that sends me back a payload with the following format :

with ['tx']['data'] the message and ['txSigned']['data'] a partially signed transaction. I'm trying to sign the message and to insert it in
the first slot of signatures[] of the transaction.

Payload in entry :

```
{'tx': {'type': 'Buffer', 'data': [2, 1, 9, 21, 196, 1, 121, 246, 8, 50, 175, 233, 165, 26, 58, 31, 47, 169, 127, 105, 114, 246, 195, 127, 107, 150, 107, 81, 27, 242, 42, 139, 211, 125, 28, 252, 5, 127, 54, 85, 153, 40, 206, 27, 171, 173, 182, 91, 139, 93, 158, 49, 186, 39, 248, 83, 155, 236, 96, 44, 203, 26, 220, 42, 251, 159, 70, 112, 234, 229, 246, 49, 247, 171, 199, 192, 75, 0, 164, 243, 164, 173, 173, 204, 108, 103, 77, 32, 29, 248, 152, 212, 87, 233, 255, 150, 147, 163, 18, 20, 46, 102, 223, 57, 126, 136, 59, 186, 161, 206, 130, 78, 143, 99, 68, 124, 54, 187, 28, 214, 169, 184, 137, 146, 121, 188, 11, 38, 234, 75, 163, 227, 159, 245, 230, 90, 36, 4, 85, 130, 248, 34, 4, 215, 246, 88, 214, 129, 157, 51, 165, 199, 101, 224, 234, 73, 209, 32, 159, 190, 135, 97, 212, 111, 105, 68, 93, 31, 113, 62, 39, 206, 222, 140, 109, 115, 71, 173, 36, 186, 212, 191, 186, 139, 47, 118, 15, 86, 147, 62, 225, 155, 19, 124, 188, 32, 130, 24, 74, 93, 25, 73, 136, 231, 60, 239, 217, 165, 75, 201, 251, 81, 250, 184, 172, 180, 74, 170, 178, 26, 93, 235, 115, 244, 5, 241, 178, 37, 12, 158, 58, 228, 224, 183, 152, 74, 250, 18, 157, 96, 7, 160, 158, 224, 142, 150, 46, 161, 202, 218, 73, 218, 230, 18, 50, 147, 194, 191, 195, 125, 8, 175, 246, 228, 16, 89, 36, 102, 175, 155, 72, 107, 229, 118, 121, 242, 246, 139, 65, 205, 220, 49, 224, 32, 146, 119, 74, 143, 99, 98, 237, 19, 164, 241, 157, 127, 75, 73, 147, 5, 131, 61, 229, 232, 186, 71, 117, 202, 167, 81, 61, 69, 95, 107, 207, 2, 115, 207, 210, 53, 247, 102, 81, 2, 23, 197, 60, 244, 161, 168, 23, 23, 33, 75, 127, 220, 222, 157, 73, 117, 58, 207, 101, 174, 28, 121, 154, 190, 255, 161, 186, 205, 218, 172, 143, 144, 113, 213, 119, 12, 213, 213, 20, 42, 184, 68, 163, 179, 252, 28, 238, 92, 2, 7, 247, 226, 10, 211, 129, 107, 192, 1, 198, 251, 136, 30, 2, 103, 195, 27, 24, 204, 62, 20, 138, 10, 82, 147, 129, 137, 32, 237, 250, 237, 171, 57, 30, 73, 51, 108, 11, 116, 219, 102, 157, 16, 71, 3, 66, 75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 136, 115, 139, 250, 198, 10, 13, 26, 130, 255, 192, 253, 225, 104, 17, 209, 176, 195, 48, 48, 68, 144, 55, 86, 179, 38, 200, 206, 101, 253, 239, 8, 209, 122, 249, 173, 94, 22, 105, 150, 178, 108, 233, 210, 121, 80, 93, 128, 143, 222, 100, 131, 254, 248, 217, 106, 235, 99, 8, 128, 8, 203, 113, 6, 221, 246, 225, 215, 101, 161, 147, 217, 203, 225, 70, 206, 235, 121, 172, 28, 180, 133, 237, 95, 91, 55, 145, 58, 140, 245, 133, 126, 255, 0, 169, 6, 167, 213, 23, 25, 44, 92, 81, 33, 140, 201, 76, 61, 74, 241, 127, 88, 218, 238, 8, 155, 161, 253, 68, 227, 219, 217, 138, 0, 0, 0, 0, 140, 151, 37, 143, 78, 36, 137, 241, 187, 61, 16, 41, 20, 142, 13, 131, 11, 90, 19, 153, 218, 255, 16, 132, 4, 142, 123, 216, 219, 233, 248, 89, 0, 11, 227, 225, 235, 161, 122, 71, 63, 137, 176, 247, 232, 226, 73, 64, 242, 10, 235, 142, 188, 167, 26, 136, 253, 233, 93, 75, 131, 183, 26, 9, 5, 33, 159, 137, 154, 129, 212, 255, 132, 251, 89, 61, 46, 223, 138, 144, 172, 27, 58, 179, 66, 88, 247, 223, 35, 62, 165, 3, 2, 177, 189, 46, 205, 33, 64, 224, 186, 130, 65, 227, 93, 10, 193, 134, 47, 123, 19, 30, 70, 242, 146, 250, 186, 131, 119, 230, 223, 15, 6, 200, 52, 135, 241, 92, 3, 20, 6, 0, 1, 2, 8, 12, 13, 17, 242, 35, 198, 137, 82, 225, 242, 182, 255, 0, 23, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 12, 0, 1, 14, 15, 2, 8, 12, 3, 8, 16, 13, 17, 34, 102, 6, 61, 18, 1, 218, 235, 234, 255, 255, 0, 23, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 20, 22, 0, 4, 1, 5, 14, 15, 2, 6, 8, 12, 7, 3, 8, 9, 8, 16, 13, 18, 19, 17, 10, 11, 42, 37, 74, 217, 157, 79, 49, 35, 6, 255, 250, 0, 23, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]}, 'txSigned': {'type': 'Buffer', 'data': [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 236, 72, 248, 210, 27, 195, 225, 195, 236, 128, 200, 183, 128, 195, 174, 10, 166, 181, 191, 241, 121, 21, 87, 232, 145, 169, 146, 168, 241, 1, 66, 204, 164, 143, 99, 121, 7, 163, 201, 176, 220, 191, 220, 99, 140, 228, 151, 111, 113, 138, 82, 86, 148, 253, 143, 194, 250, 145, 241, 152, 57, 242, 0, 2, 1, 9, 21, 196, 1, 121, 246, 8, 50, 175, 233, 165, 26, 58, 31, 47, 169, 127, 105, 114, 246, 195, 127, 107, 150, 107, 81, 27, 242, 42, 139, 211, 125, 28, 252, 5, 127, 54, 85, 153, 40, 206, 27, 171, 173, 182, 91, 139, 93, 158, 49, 186, 39, 248, 83, 155, 236, 96, 44, 203, 26, 220, 42, 251, 159, 70, 112, 234, 229, 246, 49, 247, 171, 199, 192, 75, 0, 164, 243, 164, 173, 173, 204, 108, 103, 77, 32, 29, 248, 152, 212, 87, 233, 255, 150, 147, 163, 18, 20, 8, 175, 246, 228, 16, 89, 36, 102, 175, 155, 72, 107, 229, 118, 121, 242, 246, 139, 65, 205, 220, 49, 224, 32, 146, 119, 74, 143, 99, 98, 237, 19, 46, 102, 223, 57, 126, 136, 59, 186, 161, 206, 130, 78, 143, 99, 68, 124, 54, 187, 28, 214, 169, 184, 137, 146, 121, 188, 11, 38, 234, 75, 163, 227, 159, 245, 230, 90, 36, 4, 85, 130, 248, 34, 4, 215, 246, 88, 214, 129, 157, 51, 165, 199, 101, 224, 234, 73, 209, 32, 159, 190, 135, 97, 212, 111, 105, 68, 93, 31, 113, 62, 39, 206, 222, 140, 109, 115, 71, 173, 36, 186, 212, 191, 186, 139, 47, 118, 15, 86, 147, 62, 225, 155, 19, 124, 188, 32, 130, 24, 74, 93, 25, 73, 136, 231, 60, 239, 217, 165, 75, 201, 251, 81, 250, 184, 172, 180, 74, 170, 178, 26, 93, 235, 115, 244, 5, 241, 178, 37, 12, 158, 58, 228, 224, 183, 152, 74, 250, 18, 157, 96, 7, 160, 158, 224, 142, 150, 46, 161, 202, 218, 73, 218, 230, 18, 50, 147, 194, 191, 195, 125, 164, 241, 157, 127, 75, 73, 147, 5, 131, 61, 229, 232, 186, 71, 117, 202, 167, 81, 61, 69, 95, 107, 207, 2, 115, 207, 210, 53, 247, 102, 81, 2, 23, 197, 60, 244, 161, 168, 23, 23, 33, 75, 127, 220, 222, 157, 73, 117, 58, 207, 101, 174, 28, 121, 154, 190, 255, 161, 186, 205, 218, 172, 143, 144, 113, 213, 119, 12, 213, 213, 20, 42, 184, 68, 163, 179, 252, 28, 238, 92, 2, 7, 247, 226, 10, 211, 129, 107, 192, 1, 198, 251, 136, 30, 2, 103, 195, 27, 24, 204, 62, 20, 138, 10, 82, 147, 129, 137, 32, 237, 250, 237, 171, 57, 30, 73, 51, 108, 11, 116, 219, 102, 157, 16, 71, 3, 66, 75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 136, 115, 139, 250, 198, 10, 13, 26, 130, 255, 192, 253, 225, 104, 17, 209, 176, 195, 48, 48, 68, 144, 55, 86, 179, 38, 200, 206, 101, 253, 239, 8, 209, 122, 249, 173, 94, 22, 105, 150, 178, 108, 233, 210, 121, 80, 93, 128, 143, 222, 100, 131, 254, 248, 217, 106, 235, 99, 8, 128, 8, 203, 113, 6, 221, 246, 225, 215, 101, 161, 147, 217, 203, 225, 70, 206, 235, 121, 172, 28, 180, 133, 237, 95, 91, 55, 145, 58, 140, 245, 133, 126, 255, 0, 169, 6, 167, 213, 23, 25, 44, 92, 81, 33, 140, 201, 76, 61, 74, 241, 127, 88, 218, 238, 8, 155, 161, 253, 68, 227, 219, 217, 138, 0, 0, 0, 0, 140, 151, 37, 143, 78, 36, 137, 241, 187, 61, 16, 41, 20, 142, 13, 131, 11, 90, 19, 153, 218, 255, 16, 132, 4, 142, 123, 216, 219, 233, 248, 89, 0, 11, 227, 225, 235, 161, 122, 71, 63, 137, 176, 247, 232, 226, 73, 64, 242, 10, 235, 142, 188, 167, 26, 136, 253, 233, 93, 75, 131, 183, 26, 9, 5, 33, 159, 137, 154, 129, 212, 255, 132, 251, 89, 61, 46, 223, 138, 144, 172, 27, 58, 179, 66, 88, 247, 223, 35, 62, 165, 3, 2, 177, 189, 46, 205, 33, 64, 224, 186, 130, 65, 227, 93, 10, 193, 134, 47, 123, 19, 30, 70, 242, 146, 250, 186, 131, 119, 230, 223, 15, 6, 200, 52, 135, 241, 92, 3, 20, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 17, 242, 35, 198, 137, 82, 225, 242, 182, 255, 0, 23, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 12, 0, 1, 14, 15, 2, 3, 12, 4, 3, 16, 13, 17, 34, 102, 6, 61, 18, 1, 218, 235, 234, 255, 255, 0, 23, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 20, 22, 0, 5, 1, 6, 14, 15, 2, 7, 3, 12, 8, 4, 3, 9, 3, 16, 13, 18, 19, 17, 10, 11, 42, 37, 74, 217, 157, 79, 49, 35, 6, 255, 250, 0, 23, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]}}
```

and here is my code :

```
  txSigned = tx_data['txSigned']['data']
  tx = bytes(tx_data['tx']['data'])
  client = AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
  payer = Keypair.from_secret_key(b58decode(mypkey))
  sig = payer.sign(tx)
  tra = Transaction.deserialize(bytes(txSigned))
  tra.signatures[0].signature = sig.signature
  
  tra = Transaction.serialize(tra)
  txn = await client.send_raw_transaction(tra)
```

I keep encountering : 'transaction has not been signed correctly'

Someone with a similar problem but using C# solnet : https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/issues/399

is this a bug? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, since the previous signature from Magic Eden is getting removed during `tra.signatures[0].signature = sig.signature`

Instead, you should deserialize the transaction and then sign it yourself, e.g.:

```
tra = Transaction.deserialize(bytes(txSigned))
tra.sign(payer)  
tra = Transaction.serialize(tra)
txn = await client.send_raw_transaction(tra)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I obtained "not enough signers" at line "tra.sign(payer)"

Comment: Ah that's a good sign -- you need to pass in a list of all the accounts mentioned as signers in the transaction, ie `tra.sign([payer, other_signer, other_other_signer, ...])`

Comment: "txSigned" is supposed to be a partially signed tx. With 2 signatures needed, 1 from me and 1 from "MagicEden".

MagicEden's signature is already there (I checked signatures array when deserializing "txSigned)". I tried signing the message "tx" with "payer" and putting it in the empty signature of the deserialized "txSigned" but I obtained : '"transaction has not been signed correctly"'. 

Hope I was clear enough, thanks again.

Comment: Now I understand -- I edited my response

Comment: Obtained : {'code': -32002, 'message': 'Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found', 'data': {'accounts': None, 'err': 'BlockhashNotFound', 'logs': [], 'unitsConsumed': 0}}

So I added recent_blockhash in the sig. 


Now I have : "not enough signers"

Comment: as far as I know, no one was able to do it with solana-py. There is a similar issue opened on Solnet but they managed to find a way : https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/issues/399